# How to make text on canvas "cover" a line drawn on the same canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to have text on a canvas, then immediately after the text a line to the edge of the canvas, so it should end up looking something like:

|Text Here: ----------|

but without being able to measure the exact width of the text, I'm unsure where to start the line. Therefore, I want to just draw a line across the entire canvas, place text over it, but not have the line show up under the text.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up being able to easily measure the width of the text using:

```
ctx.measureText("Text Here:").width;
```